# WordPress extremely slow loading site on first visit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a WordPress site that is running on an Amazon EC2 instance behind a load balancer.

Checking Chrome the initial connection is around 1 minute, before it proceeds to download around 3mb of content and display site.

Have a load balancer redirect setup on port 80 (HTTP) over to 443 (HTTPS) also in Route 53.
Subsequent loads are fast - assume because of cache. But struggling to figure out what is causing it.

Simply typing `pacificmh.com.au` into the browser will obviously attempt to load the HTTP version of site (?) Which hits a 301 redirect to HTTPS and after some time will load.

- https://pacificmh.com.au/ will give a certificate error `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`
- https://www.pacificmh.com.au/ is the only URL that will load quickly and correctly

Tried adding a load balancer redirect from 80 over to 443 to force HTTPS? But doesn't seem to resolve the slow loading.

[image: load balancer listener setup]

I feel like it might be to do with the certificate not covering non www version of site and load balancer redirect is to `https://pacificmh.com.au` not `https://www`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to load both urls:

- https://www.pacificmh.com.au/
- and https://pacificmh.com.au/

both load similar "fast" to me, but I'm not in your region. The certificate issue seems to be fixed with a wildcard certificate. So you need to have a certificate for every DNS entry or a wildcard (as you have).

The AWS (!) setup itself looks sound from what you describe and should't introduce any latencies. If there are latencies and slow loads I would search between ALB and EC2 and inside the Wordpress setup itself.